# Set column default with AES_ENCRYPT

Tags: mysql

I've been searching for an answer, but didn't find it.

```
'ALTER TABLE table1 ALTER COLUMN name1 SET DEFAULT AES_ENCRYPT("test1","test2")';
```

throws me an error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'AES_ENCRYPT("test1","test2")' at line 1

Is it possible to use `AES_ENCRYPT` this way?

So the problem now is: I have a field in Table A with a value AES_ENCRYPT("test1","test2")

How do I get this content in Table B as the DEFAULT VALUE for a column, so that when read from Table B with AES_DECRYPT(column,"test2"), it returns "test1"?

I've been trying in all possible ways, but I never got it working. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Yep. I think so. Leaves me with another problem, how to insert the encrypted value as defalut :-)

Comment: The accepted answer in the question linked by mvp tells you how.

Comment: Still not working. Tried to write the encrypted value to a temp field, reading that field and inserting the string as the default value. Could it be possible DEFAULT doesn't accept binary data?

Comment: as linked in duplicate, simply use a trigger with your function call inside.